# 2 Column Masonry Divs Not Flowing Correctly

Tags: css, column-count

I have some testimonials displaying in a clickable drawer called "What My Clients Are Saying" in a masonry grid. But the last testimonial isn't in the correct column.

https://amberpope.8z.com/

```css
    .testimonial {
        position: relative;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        margin-bottom: 70px;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 15px;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .testimonialmasonry {
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 2em;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="testimonialmasonry">
        <div class="testimonial">This is a testimonial</div>
        <div class="testimonial">This is also a testimonial</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well. External sites may be malicious or flagged by filter systems, and may also be removed later (making the question useless). It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Hi there. It is a div with a class of testimonialmasonry with multiple divs with a class of testimonial inside of it. Then there's just text inside of the testimonial divs.

Comment: The thing that you are describing - that the last column isn't in the "correct" column, based on what? your last testimonial is very long so if it was placed in the "right" column it would take 2 spaces, therefore the browser "chooses" the "left" column. If you short it to ~2 lines you can see it will go right

Comment: Hi Ziv, thanks for the reply. Here is a screenshot of what it currently looks like and then a mockup of what it should look like. Does that make sense? https://imgur.com/a/NXETn